# Past format without overwriting format's in place

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that copies and pastes the values/formats from a column of worksheet #1 to worksheet #3, as well as just the format from a column of worksheet #2 to worksheet #3.

I'm trying to get the copy/paste format from #2 to #3 to simply add its formats in instead of overwriting the format added from #1.

Thanks for any input.

Edit: To Clarify, I'm trying to copy the 'Fill' from worksheet #1 to worksheet #3, and the 'fill' from worksheet #2 to worksheet #3, without them cancelling another out.

So if in worksheet #1, the 5'th row is highlighted, and in worksheet #2, the 1st row is highlighted, in worksheet #3, the 5th and 1st row will be highlighted.

```
Workbooks("1").Worksheets("Combined2").Range("D1:D100").copy
            
            Workbooks("1").Worksheets("Weekly Report").Range("A1:A100").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            
            Workbooks("1").Worksheets("Combined2").Range("D1:D100").copy
            
            Workbooks("1").Worksheets("Weekly Report").Range("A1:A100").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            
            Workbooks("1").Worksheets("Combined").Range("A1:A100").copy
            
            Workbooks("1").Worksheets("Weekly Report").Range("A1:A100").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: Can you better clarify what "Paste format **without overwriting format's in place**" should mean? What "adding" format should also mean? Do you suggest that the destination range can have more formats? Are you referring to a specific format type?

Comment: The easiest way to copy highlights while not changing any other formatting would be to loop through the whole column and copy the `Cell.Interior.Color` over one-by-one. It will be slow, but you can turn off `Application.ScreenUpdating` to remove the slow-down.

Comment: What happens if you copy/paste the format then use `Workbooks("1").Worksheets("Weekly Report").Range("A1:A100").Formula = Workbooks("1").Worksheets("Combined2").Range("D1:D100").Formula`

Comment: @cyberntic.nomad 

not much, trying to build a loop now. 

`Sub Start()


Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("2")

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To LastRow

ws1.Range("D" & i).copy
ws2.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

Next i

If ws1.Range("A" & i) = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub`